# Oauth 2.0 Logout not working

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, logout

I am having a problem with the logout feature of my web app. I am using Oauth 2.0 with Google Spreadsheets to pull user data for my web app.  I have a button named 'logout' that when called will unset / revoke the Oauth 2.0 access token granted. I am using PHP 5.5.4. Code snippet follows:

```
//If the request contains a logout query, destroy the access token.

if(isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
   unset($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN']);
   echo "Logged out";
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN'])) {
   die('Access denied');
}
```

All works, but when the user clicks the back button in their browser, they are redirected back to my app instead of being presented the message in the second if statement and PHP exiting the script. I am testing on localhost. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!